# how to add json array to json object dynamically onclick in android?

Tags: android, android-json

I'm trying to add JSON array to JSON object on click event in android. how to do it? any suggestions?

I have multiple JSON arrays based on conditions. when I click on something that particular JSON array should be updated to a common JSON object. I'm able to create JSON array on clicking an element and able to add it to object.

```
if (seat_name.equals("L2")) {
        try {
            l2.put("seat_name", seat_name);
            l2_array.put(l2);
            l2_obj.put("L2", l2_array);
            Log.d("L2--",""+l2_obj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (seat_name.equals("L3")) {
        try {
            l3.put("seat_name", seat_name);
            l3_array.put(l3);
            l3_obj.put("L3", l3_array);
            Log.d("L3--",""+l3_obj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm able to create a single array for the object. what I want is to add the array to an object when I click on different elements.
when I click on the first element it gives me correct JSON output. but when I click on the second element, 2nd arrays overrides the first array and creates new JSON object with the same data rather than first and second array.

Comment: Is the code you provided the onClick method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both arrays in the same object, then you have to use a common object in both cases:

```
if (seat_name.equals("L2")) {
    try {
        l2.put("seat_name", seat_name);
        l2_array.put(l2);
        common_obj.put("L2", l2_array);
        Log.d("L2--",""+ common_obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else if (seat_name.equals("L3")) {
    try {
        l3.put("seat_name", seat_name);
        l3_array.put(l3);
        common_obj.put("L3", l3_array);
        Log.d("L3--",""+ common_obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```